How to open up specific PowerShell script in PowerShell ISE via URL
I want to be able to share links that automatically open a script in the PowerShell ISE. For now, my workaround is to share a link directly to the saved script item in the Content Editor using the fo query string like this:
https://www.mysite.com/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Editor.aspx?sc_bw=1&fo={xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}
From there, the script item can be right clicked and you can Edit with ISE.
How might I be able to do the equivalent of fo on the PowerShell ISE page (/sitecore/shell/Applications/PowerShell/PowerShellIse?sc_bw=1&sc_lang=en), if at all?

I was able to successfully open the ISE using this URL :
https://www.mysite.com/sitecore/shell/applications/powershell/powershellise?id={xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}&db=master

Please try the same.

That works. Thank you. The db=master query string portion is definitely necessary as well, otherwise the server throws the exception Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='']

sc_bw=1 is also required if you want the UI to work properly. For example, list views will not appear and IDs written to the console will not be clickable. You also won't see the topmost ribbon with the Sitecore blocks button, log out button, or user avatar.
